# Permutation group on $n$ points that has $n-1$ cycles avoiding any point

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm curious if we can classify permutation groups on $n$ points such that for each of those points the group has an $n-1$ cycle avoiding this point. Evidently $S_n$ and $A_{2n}$ with their natural actions satisfy this. The only other groups I know with this property are $M_{12}$ and $M_{24}$ with their actions of $12$ and $24$ points, which is what made me raise the question: it seems difficult for a group to contain so many cycles without being symmetric or alternating.

Do the above examples exhaust all such permutation groups (note that the other Mathieu groups don't have this property)? Or are there other examples, and what can we say about them? One can easily show such a group must be $2$-transitive (with a trivial exception); maybe finding a argument that such groups must be $k$-transitive for $k>2$ is possible, which would help as $4$ transitive groups are classified.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding the question properly: if $G$ is your group acting on $X$, is the condition "for every $x\in X$, there exists a permutation $\sigma\in G$ that fixes $x$ and permutes the elements of $X\setminus\{x\}$ in a single cycle of length $n-1$"?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean.

Comment: It is known that a $2$-transitive group is affine or almost simple, and there is some kind of classification of these groups, so this probably could be resolved. But there are plenty fo examples besides the ones you mentioned: $AGL(1,q)$, for $q$ a prime power, $PSL(2,p)$ acting on $p+1$ points, and plenty of others. Even $M_{11}$ on 12 points, for example.

Comment: Here is the count of the number of such groups up to degree 20 : [ 2, 0 ]
[ 3, 1 ]
[ 4, 2 ]
[ 5, 2 ]
[ 6, 4 ]
[ 7, 2 ]
[ 8, 7 ]
[ 9, 4 ]
[ 10, 2 ]
[ 11, 2 ]
[ 12, 6 ]
[ 13, 2 ]
[ 14, 4 ]
[ 15, 1 ]
[ 16, 8 ]
[ 17, 2 ]
[ 18, 4 ]
[ 19, 2 ]
[ 20, 4 ]

Comment: I think $M_{11} on 12 points doesn't do this: it always fixes one of the points, no 11 cycle through avoiding any point (except one). It doesn't work on 11 points either, just look at the conjugacy classes of it.

Comment: $M_{11}$ has a transitive action on $12$ points (this is not directly related to its usual action on $11$ points).

Comment: Oh, forgive me, my bad! That's fascinating! Where can I hear about that?

Comment: The normalizer in $S_p$ of a $p$-cycle has this property, and they are sharply 2-transitive.

Comment: A $2$-transitive group on $(p+1)$ points, for any prime $p$ will give some examples, other than $S_n$, $A_n$, but we should consider them in a different way. Also, $S_5$ acts transitively on $6$ letters, and stabiliszer of each point has order $20$, so contains a $5$-cycle.

Comment: @BerenGunsolus For every group $G$ and subgroup $H$, you get a transitive action on the set of cosets of $H$ by multiplication. (And, in fact, every transitive action arises this way, in some sense.) If $H$ is core-free in $G$, then this action is faithful, so you get a permutation group. $M_{11}$ has a subgroup of index $12$ (isomorphic to $PSL(2,11)$) so this is where this action comes from. It turns out that it is  3-transitive. You can find a bit more information on the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M11 and a list of references.